# three.js - scaling/transforming of tube geometry

Tags: three.js

I've a tube geometry with 174 points, 12 radius segment, 100 radius and 174 segments.
When I double click at any part of a tube, the scaled portion of a tube with +/- 8 points will be displayed.
Now the issue is when I click at bending part of a tube, the scaled portion does not look as good as I click on a straight part of a tube.

Please find below the 2 images.[image: 3d full piipe][image: portion selected at bend]

Please find [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WT6jL/23/) here.

Please find below the code of scaling.

```
tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(extrudePath, segments, 100, radiusSegments, closed, debug);           
            tube.dynamic = true;

            tube.computeBoundingBox();
            console.log(tube);          
            tube.scale.x = tube.boundingBox.max.x;
            tube.scale.z = tube.boundingBox.max.z;
```

**Is there anyway to scale it properly or transform that bending portion into cylinder so that it looks like the straight portion of a tube ?**

Answer (score 0):

I think the scaling you are doing is improper. Since the section you are trying to scale may not have its axis along the y axis, scaling the x and z parameters only will result in distortion. Is it possible to know the axis of the section? Then there are 2 ways -

1) Rotate the section so the axis is aligned with y axis, scale x and z coordinates and rotate the section back.

2) Come up with a formula to scale a cylinder with axis in arbitrary direction.

Since this is a very old question you probably have the answer already. Please let me know if I am wrong and what worked for you.